# Can't read .xlsx file on Azure Databricks

Tags: python, excel, pyspark, databricks

I'm on Azure databricks notebooks using Python, and I'm having trouble reading an excel file and putting it in a spark dataframe.

I saw that there were topics of the same problems, but they don't seem to work for me.

I tried the following solution:

https://sauget-ch.fr/2019/06/databricks-charger-des-fichiers-excel-at-scale/

I did add the credentials to access my files on Azure Data Lake.

After installing all the libraries I needed, I'm doing this code :

```py
import xlrd
import azure.datalake.store

filePathBsp = projectFullPath + "BalanceShipmentPlan_20190724_19h31m37s.xlsx";
bspDf = pd.read_excel(AzureDLFileSystem.open(filePathBsp))
```

There, I use:

```
"AzureDLFileSystem.open"
```

to get the file in Azure Data Lake because:

```
"pd.read_excel"
```

doesn't let me get my file to the Lake.

The problem is, it gives me this error :

```
TypeError: open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

I'm sure I can access this file because when I try:

```
spark.read.csv(filePathBsp)
```

he can find my file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after long days of researchs, i've finally found the solution.

Here it is !

First, you have to import the library "spark-Excel" in your cluster.
Here's the page for this library : https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

You also need the library "spark_hadoopOffice", or you'll get the following exception later :

```
java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils
```

[image]

Take care about the version of Scala in your cluster when you download the libraries, it's important.

Then, you have to mount the credentials for Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) This way :

```
# Mount point
udbRoot = "****"

configs = {
   "dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": "ClientCredential",
   "dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id": "****",
   "dfs.adls.oauth2.credential": "****",
   "dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/token"
}

# unmount 
#dbutils.fs.unmount(udbRoot)

# Mounting
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "adl://****",
  mount_point = udbRoot,
  extra_configs = configs
)
```

You need to do the mount command only once.

Then, you can do this code line :

```
testDf = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("useHeader", True).load(fileTest)
display(testDf)
```

Here you go ! You have a Spark Dataframe from an Excel File in Azure Data Lake Storage !

It worked for me, hopefully it will help someone else.

Comment: How do you read a specific sheet from the xlsx file. I have used the `.option("sheetName", "Info")` but reads the first sheet irrespective of sheet name mentioned.

Comment: Do something like that : 

`.option("dataAddress", "Sheet!")`

In your case, the property that you need is "dataAddress", and you forgot the "!" at the end of your sheet name. If you don't put it, it won't work.